Value of $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \left(\frac{1}{(x- i \epsilon)^a} - \frac{1}{(x+ i \epsilon)^a}\right)$?
I am trying to obtain a relation which generalises
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{x-i \epsilon} - \frac{1}{x+i \epsilon}\right) = 2 \pi i \delta(x)
$$
for some generic power $a$ of the exponent, in the way
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \left(\frac{1}{(x- i \epsilon)^a} - \frac{1}{(x+ i \epsilon)^a}\right) = ...
$$
I was trying to obtain the result by some contour  deformation in the $x$ complex plane around the two branch cuts along the imaginary line which have a branch point at $i \epsilon$ and $- i \epsilon$ respectively (which I believe to be possible to do as long as $\Re(a)>1$) but I keep on finding zero in the end...

Extending the comment of @Triatticus, is $a \in \mathbb{C}$? Perhaps only $a \in \mathbb{R}$? As you know, exponentiation is not well-defined without choosing a particular branch of the logarithm according to the usual definition of $b^z := \exp(z \log b)$.

How "generic" is $a$?  Positive integer?  Integer?  Real?  Complex?

You'll have better luck with a different generalization, namely the one-sided distributional limit$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\epsilon^{a-1}\left(\frac{1}{(x-i\epsilon)^a}-\frac{1}{(x+i\epsilon)^a}\right),$$since it's of the form $\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{1}{\epsilon}f\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right).$

I'm rusty, but look at the Laplace transform n-1th power with frequency shift $H(t) e^{\pm i\epsilon}\frac{t^{a-1}}{(a-1)!}$   $ \sqsupset $   $ \frac{1}{(x\mp i\epsilon)^{a}}$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

It is interesting to point out that for even $a$, since at $x=0$ your limit reduces to
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{i^a[1-(-1)^a]}{\epsilon^a},$$ then, it is $0$.
If $x\neq 0$, the limit yields $0$ as well, so the limit is $0$ $\forall x$.

A priori $a$ is a complex number, however, I would already be interested in the result when $a$ is a negative integer

I'm sorry @HugdeRoda I'm not sure I understand why the limit when $x$ is different from 0 is also 0

Not sure how much it helps, but the limand is equivalent to $\frac{2i\sin(-\frac{ia}{2} \log(\frac{x + i\epsilon}{x - i\epsilon}))}{(x^2 + \epsilon^2)^{a/2}}$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem

@TheTiler I did see this page but this theorem is just the equality when $a=1$ which is already known right?

When $x\not=0$, then $\lim_{\epsilon\to0}(x\pm i\epsilon)^{-a}=x^{-a}$, if we assume $x^{-a}$ is a continuous function except at $x=0$. So the total limit evaluates to $0$ when $x\not=0$ (no matter what $a$ is). And if $x=0$, for $a\in\mathbb{R}{< 0}$, the limit is $\lim{\epsilon\to0^+}\left((-i\epsilon)^{-a}-(i\epsilon)^{-a}\right)=0^{-a}-0^{-a}=0$, since $z^{-a}$ is a continuous function when $a\in\mathbb{R}_{<0}$, even at $z=0$.

In the classical treatise by I. M. Gel'fand and G. E. Shilov (1964), Generalized functions. Vol. I: Properties and operations, Boston, MA: Academic Press, pp. xviii+423, ISBN 978-0-12-279501-5, MR0166596, Zbl 0115.33101, gives a complete study of the distributions $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} (x \pm i\varepsilon)^{\alpha}\triangleq (x \pm i 0)^{\alpha}$ for every $\alpha \in\Bbb C$, then it is possible to construct every distribution given by their difference.

...following from the preceding comment, it should be note that the analytic structure of $(x \pm i 0)^{\alpha}$ significantly changes depending on the real part of $\alpha$: this means that for $\Re \alpha>-1$ it has a given expression, while for  $\Re \alpha\le-1$ the expression is very different. This gives a somewhat complex expression for their differences and this is possibly the reason you do not find it frequently shown in the literature.

@DanieleTampieri are you refering to the section 4.5 of chapter 1 where they Taylor expand the series? I found the construction a bit unclear

NoName, the generalized functions $(x \pm i0)^\alpha$ are introduced before, in paragraph 3.6 of chapter 1, when $\Re \alpha>-1$: then they are defined for all the values of $\alpha$ by analytic continuation, and this is done in the subsequent sections, particularly 4.4, though their structure relies on the distributions $x_+^\alpha$, $x_-^\alpha$ defined in paragraph 3.2.

... [continued from the previous comment ]. I agree with you that their development is a bit tortuous and involved (and this is the main reason for which I decided to not post an answer). Nevertheless, If you are really interested, it possibly would require just a few hours of reading to write down a concrete expression.

Not strictly an answer to the question, but  may be helpful:
It is claimed in M. Besken, J.de Boer, G. Mathys On local and integrated stress-tensor commutators ArXiv 2012.15724 that, for $h\in {\mathbb Z}$  we have the following distribution
$$
f_h(t,r) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left( \frac{1}{((-t-i\epsilon)^2+r^2)^h} -  \frac{1}{((-t+i\epsilon)^2+r^2)^h} 
\right)\nonumber\\
=-\frac{2\pi i}{(h-1)}\Big[ (t-r)^{-h} \partial^{h-1}_t \delta(t+r) +  (t+r)^{-h} \partial^{h-1}_t \delta(t-r)\Big]\nonumber
$$
For $h<0$ and not an integer they claim
$$
f_h(t,r)=\sin \pi h(t^2-r^2)^{-h} (\theta(t-r)+ \theta(-t-r))
$$
I have not verified these claims.

This looks a bit sketchy at $h=1$.

For what it is worth, the Poisson kernel representation
$$ {\rm Im}\frac{1}{x-i0^+}~=~\pi\delta(x) \tag{1}$$
of the Dirac delta distribution generalizes to
$$ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}:~~{\rm Im}\frac{1}{(x-i0^+)^n}~=~\pi(n-1)! (-D)^{n-1}\delta(x). \tag{2}$$
Eq. (2) in turn suggests that
$$ \forall a\in\mathbb{R}_+:~~{\rm Im}\frac{1}{(x-i0^+)^a}~\stackrel{?}{=}~\pi\Gamma(a) (-D)^{a-1}\delta(x), \tag{3}$$
using a fractional derivative, although I have currently not had time to verify this conjecture.
